# Converting date in SMA data calculated in TTR package to POSIXct

Tags: r

I am using `TTR` package for calculating SMA in R. I want to use the result to plot a graph in `HighCharts`.

Here is my code:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GS")
d<-SMA(GS[,1],4)
head(d,5)

            GS.Open.SMA.4
 2007-01-03            NA
 2007-01-04            NA
 2007-01-05            NA
 2007-01-08       199.575
 2007-01-09       200.310
```

I want to convert the date into unix time format. But I am not able to get the date separately. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2014-11-16", format="%Y-%m-%d”))
[1] 1416092400
```

to convert.

P.S.
Have a look at the [rCharts](http://rcharts.io/) package as well.